# Headline for teaching Bubble

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, office-ui-fabric-react

Trying to show HTML data to teaching bubble headline but getting below error.

Any idea how can I resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headline attribute in TeachingBubble component needs a string value.
[image]

As a workaround,we could add html element in the content part.
[image]

Test code:

```
{teachingBubbleVisible && (
        <TeachingBubble
          target="#targetButton"
          primaryButtonProps={examplePrimaryButtonProps}
          secondaryButtonProps={exampleSecondaryButtonProps}
          onDismiss={toggleTeachingBubbleVisible}
          
        >
            <h1>Discover what’s trending around youw</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, nulla, ipsum? Molestiae quis aliquam magni
          harum non?
        </TeachingBubble>
      )}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation at [ITeachingBubbleProps interface - headline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-ui-fabric-react/iteachingbubbleprops?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#headline),

`headline` property expects `string` value. So you have to pass the string value to headline property of `TeachingBubble` element.

If want to apply additional styling to headline then you can use:

[ITeachingBubbleStyles interface - headline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/react-internal/iteachingbubblestyles?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#headline)